# jquery broken on post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am new to webdevelopement and Jquery
I have an aspx page with a radiolist (3 ) items and  3 divs
I hide all 3 on startup

on a post back i am checking and if there is a button selected I am trying to use jquery again to show that div
can some one check and see where i went wrong

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RdoListAdminTasks"  runat="server" BackColor ="SkyBlue">
    <asp:ListItem Text = "Add Employee" >Add Employee</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text = "EditEmployee">Edit Employee</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text = "AddCCB">Add CCB</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   var rbvalue = $("input[@name=<%=RdoListAdminTasks.UniqueID%>]:radio:checked").val();

        rbvalue=rbvalue;

        if (typeof rbvalue == 'undefined'){
                    $().ready(function() {
                    $('.AddCCB').hide();
                    $('.EditEmployee').hide();
                    $('.Add_Employee').hide();


                                           });
        }   

        else{
        switch (rbvalue){

            case 'Add Employee':
                              $('.AddCCB').fadeOut('fast');
                              $('.EditEmployee').fadeOut('fast');
                              $('.Add_Employee').fadeIn('slow'); 
                              break;
            case 'Edit Employee':            
                                $('.AddCCB').fadeOut('fast');
                                $('.Add_Employee').fadeOut('fast');        
                                $('.EditEmployee').fadeIn('slow');
                                break;
             case 'Add CCB':
                                $('.EditEmployee').fadeOut('fast');
                                $('.Add_Employee').fadeOut('fast');
                                $('.AddCCB').fadeIn('slow');
                                break;
            default:
                                alert("How'd you get here? Who sent you?");
                                $('.AddCCB').fadeOut('fast');
                                $('.EditEmployee').fadeOut('fast');
                                $('.Add_Employee').fadeOut('fast');
                                break; 





        }



        } 

     </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong here :
missing `doucment.ready` function. also:

```
 $('.AddCCB').hide();
```

`.` DOT here represents `cssClass`  here which I cant see you have assigned any where.

If you want to hide with ID :

```
 $('#<%= AddCCB.ClientID %>').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your page is not fully rendered when that script is running.

Try using [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
function UpdateUIDisplay() {
    var rbvalue = $("input[@name=<%=RdoListAdminTasks.UniqueID%>]:radio:checked").val();

    rbvalue=rbvalue;

    if (typeof rbvalue == 'undefined'){
                $().ready(function() {
                $('.AddCCB').hide();
                $('.EditEmployee').hide();
                $('.Add_Employee').hide();


                                       });
    }   

    else{
    switch (rbvalue){

        case 'Add Employee':
                          $('.AddCCB').fadeOut('fast');
                          $('.EditEmployee').fadeOut('fast');
                          $('.Add_Employee').fadeIn('slow'); 
                          break;
        case 'Edit Employee':            
                            $('.AddCCB').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.Add_Employee').fadeOut('fast');        
                            $('.EditEmployee').fadeIn('slow');
                            break;
         case 'Add CCB':
                            $('.EditEmployee').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.Add_Employee').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.AddCCB').fadeIn('slow');
                            break;
        default:
                            alert("How'd you get here? Who sent you?");
                            $('.AddCCB').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.EditEmployee').fadeOut('fast');
                            $('.Add_Employee').fadeOut('fast');
                            break; 





    }



    } 
 }

 $(function() { UpdateUIDisplay(); });
 </script>
```